# how to create switch structure comparing strings in latex

Tags: programming

I want to process options that get passed to a package with [`kvoptions`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions).

The string is then saved in `\bugs@errorlevel`.
I want to test if it contains one of [info, warning, error] and 
set a command accordingly.

I could think of setting a bool variable to false and test as long as it has been set true or remains false. That could be done by cascading if expressions.

Testing strings for being equal can for example be done with [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\ifstrequal` or [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring)'s `\IfStrEq`. Both are of the `\ifthen` package type using brackets.

On the other hand a 'real' switch could be done with the package [`boolexpr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/boolexpr).
However in that case I need commands which return a pure bool expression, which neither of the above commands do. The sequence principle would be:

```
\switch
\case{6>1 \AND 6<=5}$\geq 1$ and $\leq 5$%
\case{3<10}$> 5$ and $< 10$%
\case{3>10}$\geq 10$%
\endswitch
```

However I do not now what to enter in the case structure for comparison of strings.
In the end it should be something like

```
\switch
\case{\isequal{\bugs@errorlevel}{info}}
   \renewcommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageInfo{templatebugs}{#1}{}}%
\case{\isequal{\bugs@errorlevel}{warning}}
   \renewcommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageWarning{templatebugs}{#1}{}}%
\case{\isequal{\bugs@errorlevel}{error}}
   \renewcommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageError{templatebugs}{#1}{}}%
\otherwise
   \PackageError{templatebugs}{
     \MessageBreak
     value >\bugs@errorlevel< unkown \MessageBreak
     possible values are: info,warning,error. \MessageBreak
   }{}
\endswitch
```

but that code does not work, since `\isequal` does not exist.

Comment: It seems that etoolbox and boolexpr are not compatible. Is it the case for you ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a similar vein to Andrey's answer, but sticking with a wrapper that works with `boolexpr`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boolexpr,pdftexcmds,trace}
\makeatletter
\long\def\isequal#1#2{\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}}
\def\bugs@errorlevel{error}
\def\tplbugs@BugAction#1{}
\switch
\case{\isequal{\bugs@errorlevel}{info}}
   \renewcommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageInfo{templatebugs}{#1}{}}%
\case{\isequal{\bugs@errorlevel}{warning}}
   \renewcommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageWarning{templatebugs}{#1}{}}%
\case{\isequal{\bugs@errorlevel}{error}}
   \renewcommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageError{templatebugs}{#1}{}}%
\otherwise
   \PackageError{templatebugs}{
     \MessageBreak
     value >\bugs@errorlevel< unkown \MessageBreak
     possible values are: info,warning,error. \MessageBreak
   }{}
\endswitch
\show\tplbugs@BugAction
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the pdfTeX's primitive `\pdfstrcmp`. Quoting the pdfTeX manual:

> This command compares two strings and expands to 0 if the strings are
>   equal, to -1 if the first string ranks before the second, and to 1
>   otherwise.

Moreover, the package [`pdftexcmds`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds) provides a similar `\pdf@strcmp` command that works for all TeX engines.

So, the proof-of-concept code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\switch}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{info}=0
    first%
  \else\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{warning}=0
    second%
  \else\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{error}=0
    third%
  \else
    unknown%
  \fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\switch{info}
\switch{warning}
\switch{error}
\switch{something}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to go the old TeX way, you can use the `\ifx` conditional, which tests for equality of tokens. If the two following tokens after `\ifx` are macros, their parameter text and replacement text is compared.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\infotext{info}
\def\warningtext{warning}
\def\errortext{error}
\newcommand{\switch}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\tmp{#1}%
    \ifx\tmp\infotext
      first%
    \else\ifx\tmp\warningtext
      second%
    \else\ifx\tmp\errortext
      third%
    \else
      unknown%
    \fi\fi\fi
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\switch{info}
\switch{warning}
\switch{error}
\switch{something}

\end{document}
```

Beware that `\ifx` considers `\long` and `\outer` in macro definitions, so mixing `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*` or `\def` definitions will not succeed to compare!

Comment: The problem with the `\ifx` approach is that it's not expandable. So it can't be used, for example, in `boolexpr`'s `\switch` construction.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\makeatletter
\def\bugs@errorlevel{info} % change for testing

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_case_str:onn { \bugs@errorlevel }
  {
   {info}    { \providecommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageInfo{templatebugs}{#1}} }
   {warning} { \providecommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageWarning{templatebugs}{#1}} }
   {error}   { \providecommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageError{templatebugs}{#1}} }
  }
  {
   % set a default
   \providecommand\tplbugs@BugAction[1]{\PackageError{templatebugs}{#1}}
   % issue an error
   \PackageError{templatebugs}
     {
      \MessageBreak
      value~>\bugs@errorlevel<~unkown \MessageBreak
      possible~values~are:~info,~warning,~error.
     }
     {
      The~value~must~be~one~of~`info',~`warning',~or~`error';
      \MessageBreak
      I'll~do~as~if~`error'~had~been~requested
     }
   }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\show\tplbugs@BugAction
```